# WP-nivo-slider Producing Error "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..."

Tags: plugins, errors

I have installed the [wp-nivo-slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-nivo-slider/) and am now getting a list of these errors on my /wp-admin/ page.

The error is:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /html/wp-content/plugins/wp-nivo-slider/wp-nivo-slider.php:633) in /html/wp-login.php on line 354
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is typically from there being extra spaces after the final closing ?> tag in a plugin file, or possibly even your wp-config.php file.

Comment: That is it. For some reason the wp-nivo-slider.php was too spaced out (extra line breaks). Probably a file encoding thing. Thank you!